# Share config files across environments in Solr

Tags: solr

We have several environments (incl. several development, staging and production), but currently copy and paste the Solr `conf` folders and setup `solr-data-config.xml` for each environment as the file has the environments details:

```
<dataConfig>
    <dataSource name="ds-db" type="JdbcDataSource"
                driver="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver"
                url="jdbc:mysql://10.0.0.40:3306/***"
                user="***"
                password="**"/>
```

How can we separate the solr config from the environment data, so that we just have one config folder per search group and have separate environment data?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would recommend to externalise the environment dependent parameters :

1) **DIH**

You can obtain this using placeholders :
e.g.

```
<dataConfig>
    <dataSource name="ds-db" type="JdbcDataSource"
                driver="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver"
                url ="${dataimporter.request.url}"
                user ="${dataimporter.request.user}"
                password ="${dataimporter.request.password}"/>
```

2) **Solrconfig**

```
<requestHandler name="/dataimport" class="solr.DataImportHandler">
        <lst name="defaults">
            <str name="config">data-config.xml</str>
            <str name="clean">true</str>
            ...
            <str name="url">${db.url:defaultUrl}</str>
            <str name="user">${db.user:defaultUser}</str>
            <str name="password">${db.password:}</str>
            ...
        </lst>
    </requestHandler>
```

${environment_variable: "default" } is the syntax to use[1] .

Then you need to pass the variables as Java system properties for the Solr java process.

[1] https://lucene.apache.org/solr/guide/6_6/configuring-solrconfig-xml.html#Configuringsolrconfig.xml-JVMSystemProperties

Comment: Thanks! It makes sense, but not sure about implementation. `2)` doesn't seem to apply to me as I don't have any settings there in my files, just in `solr-data-config.xml`. Where would it pull e.g `${dataimporter.request.url}` from? Or where would I add these?

Comment: You need to add those lines in the solrconfig.xml .
The solr-data-config will fetch the variables from the Solrconfig.xml that will fetch the variables from JVM system properties.

Comment: Ah ok, I understand the extra lines now. Same question still pretty much though :-) "_will fetch the variables from JVM system properties_" - How/where do I add this?

Comment: From the Solr wiki I linked :
you could override this using a JVM system property by launching the Solr it with:

bin/solr start -Dsolr.lock.type=none
In general, any Java system property that you want to set can be passed through the bin/solr script using the standard -Dproperty=value syntax. Alternatively, you can add common system properties to the SOLR_OPTS environment variable defined in the Solr include file (bin/solr.in.sh or bin/solr.in.cmd). For more information about how the Solr include file works, refer to: Taking Solr to Production.

Comment: I've got it to work using the `bin/solr.in.sh`! Only issue on our side now is that we have 3 sites running on the same server currently. So this solution will work perfectly on different (virtual) machines, but this set up will conflict with the collections for each site :-(

Comment: Do you mean you have 3 core on the same Solr server ?
This should be fine, just use JVM system properties such as :
collection1.user, collection2.user ect ect

Then in the solrconfig (which is per Core) just use those variables.
It should be ok

Comment: It is 3 systems that are the same. So we have production, staging and demo on the same server, using the same core. So names like `core1_production`, `core1_staging`, etc. So currently in our code we check the website environment and select the correct core based on that. It's a bit of an oversight of mine, thinking we can achieve what I wanted in my post. For different servers it's perfect, but doesn't work here as it's 3 different versions of a site with their own DB.

Comment: @Richard how did u solve this? facing same issue and i am a solr noob

Comment: @KingsleySimon I'm not working with it anymore, but this answer helped. You can set up environment variables in a `solr.in.sh` file (maybe `/etc/default/solr.in.sh`) that you can then pass through. Works really well once set up